# Trying to write a function that simulates a cellphone dial up

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a function that i need to write, called dial_up, it gets a string as input and returns a word as output.

```
e.g def dial_up('999 666 88'):
```

expected output:

```
'YOU'
```

just like you are dialing up a msg on a old phone, but i have no idea how to start maybe with something like this:

```
def dial_up(string):
"""
"""


dict = {'2': 'abc', '3': 'def', '4': 'ghi', '5': 'jkl', '6': 'mno', '7': 'pqrt', '8': 'tuv', '9': 'wxyz'}
for key, value in groupby(string):
```

after this im kinda stuck.

Obs: i need my function to loop so if i write ('2222') it returns me 'a' since it goes back to 'a',  'a' -> 'b' -> 'c' -> 'a'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses `groupby`. It uses the `groupby` key to locate the correct digit string in the dictionary, and it uses the length of the `groupby` group to index into that string. The group is returned as an iterator, so we need to turn it into a list to get its length, and we need to subtract one to calculate the correct index, since indices are zero-based. And then we can implement cycling by reducing this index modulo the length of the dictionary's digit string.

I changed the name of your dictionary, since `string` is the name of a standard Python module.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from itertools import groupby

decode = {'2': 'ABC', '3': 'DEF', '4': 'GHI', '5': 'JKL', 
    '6': 'MNO', '7': 'PQRT', '8': 'TUV', '9': 'WXYZ'}

def dial_up(digits):
    #return ''.join([decode[key][len(list(value)) - 1]
    result = []
    for key, value in groupby(digits):
        if key == ' ':
            continue
        i = len(list(value)) - 1
        s = decode[key]
        result.append(s[i % len(s)])
    return ''.join(result)

# Test

data = (
    '999 666 88', 
    '33 99 8', 
    '222 2 22', 
    '22 22', 
    '2222', 
    '444 43',
)

for s in data:
    print(s, dial_up(s))
```

**output**

```
999 666 88 YOU
33 99 8 EXT
222 2 22 CAB
22 22 BB
2222 A
444 43 IGD
```

Tested on Python 2.6.6, but it should also work correctly on Python 3.

Comment: Goddamn i wish i could write that as fast as you im where rolling my head around for 2 days, thank you, about the python i have both 2.7 and 3.x so its not really a problem. ;).

Comment: Btw im sry the future module it's when im running the script on a older version of python and the itertools module might not exist?

Comment: @EXT: The `from __future__ import print_function` lets you use the `print()` function in Python 2. It has no effect on the `itertools` import. If you try to run this script on a really old version of Python that doesn't have `itertools.groupby`, then it will fail.

Comment: so lets assume i just want the returned value, i can just delete everything below that and not use the __future__ module, TIL. I suck at using modules i dont know most of them, i guess it comes from experience. It makes your job so much easier.

Comment: @EXT: Yes, you can get rid of the `__future__` import. And you can delete the stuff below the `# Test` comment. You only need the `from itertools import groupby`, the `decode` dictionary definition, and the `dial_up` function definition.

Comment: To make the function not get out of index range you divided the len of the list with the len of the dicionary keys.

Comment: @EXT: Sort of. `i % len(s)` is the _remainder_ of dividing `i` by `len(s)`, so it's always >=0 and < `len(s)`, which ensures it's a valid index for `s`.

Answer (score 2):

```
num2chars = {'2': 'abc', '3': 'def', '4': 'ghi', '5': 'jkl', '6': 'mno', '7': 'pqrt', '8': 'tuv', '9': 'wxyz'}

def dial_up(string):
    message = ""
    for group in string.split(" "):
        message += num2chars[group[0]][len(group)-1]
    return message
```

Or:

```
def dial_up(string):
    return "".join(num2chars[group[0]][len(group)-1] for group in string.split())
```

Comment: if i try writing something, like these dial_up('222222') without the spaces gives me index out of range is it possible to write it so when it gets to 222 goes back to zero, and starts checking again, if that makes sense so the output should be 'abc'. Anyway thank you so much for your help, thats way easier than i though , i guess i need a lot more practice.

Comment: @EXT: '222222' without any spaces is ambiguous. Why should the output be 'ABC' and not 'CAB' or 'BBB' or 'CC', etc?

Comment: @PM 2Ring  yea you are right, just check it now myself, but if i run ('2223 3') it should give me 'cdd' or 'ce' atleast. do i need to do a if statement to check the len of the string and if it is > than 4 it goes back?

Comment: @PM2Ring about your question to make it clear i need, my function to loop, ('2222') gives me 'a' since it goes 'a' -> 'b' -> 'c' -> 'a'.

Comment: @EXT: Should '22 22' also return 'a', or should it return 'b b'?

Comment: @PM2Ring  in this case the space is just like a normal space in the dial up without actually putting in the space; e.g ('444 43') returns 'igd'